# Rails display current controller errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The problem is really simple. I want to display error notifications outside `simple_form_for` tag for every controller in my app.

I use the following code:

```
- if @user.errors.present?
  .alert-box.alert{ data: { alert: true } }
    %div= t('simple_form.error_notification.default_message')
```

Which is OK, but only for one controller with `@user` variable. I want to know if there is some clever way to get this class instance variable (`@user`) without hardcoding the name. In each controller its different but it corresponds with current controller name `@user` for `UsersController` etc.

Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I can accept only one answer :)

### Possible solution

I end up with helper method:

```
  def errors_present?
    # returns string like "UsersController" with support for name-spaced controllers
    controller_name = controller.class.to_s.split('::').last

    # extract out the "user" portion
    prefix_name = controller_name.gsub(/controller/i, '').singularize.downcase

    # is there a defined instance variable with this name?
    i_var = controller.instance_variable_get(:"@#{prefix_name}")

    return i_var.errors.present? if i_var != nil

    false
  end
```

and view code:

```
- if errors_present?
  .alert-box.alert{ data: { alert: true } }
    %div= t('simple_form.error_notification.default_message')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to do this in a dynamic route than you'll need to ensure that the instance variable you use matches what can be inferred from the controller name. You can then use this in a helper method.

```
  def controller_error_present
    # returns string like "UsersController" with support for name-spaced controllers
    controller_name = controller.class.to_s.split('::').last

    # extract out the "user" portion
    prefix_name = controller_name.gsub(/controller/i, '').singularize.downcase

    # is there a defined instance variable with this name?
    controller.instance_variable_get(:"@#{prefix_name}") != nil
  end
```

To be used like:

```
- if controller_error_present
 .alert-box.alert{ data: { alert: true } }
    %div= t('simple_form.error_notification.default_message')
```

As long as you initialize a `@user` variable in your controller than it will be picked up by the instance variable check.

Comment: Your controller_error_present method never actually checks to see if errors are present.  It only checks to see if the instance variable exists.

Comment: @infused you're right - I missed that. Fortunately its a trivial fix :)

Answer (score 1):

If all of your controllers follow the same naming convention, then the instance variable name is the singular name of the controller. You can replace `@user` with the following:

```
instance_variable_get("@#{controller.controller_name.singularize}")
```

If you move that into a helper method in application_helper.rb:

```
def controller_record
  instance_variable_get("@#{controller.controller_name.singularize}")
end
```

You can then reference controller_record in your view:

```
- if controller_record.errors.present?
  .alert-box.alert{ data: { alert: true } }
  %div= t('simple_form.error_notification.default_message')
```